# Increment logic not working properly

Tags: java, for-loop

I have to increment the inner loop based on the outer loop, but my logic is failing.

```
int size = currencyList.size();

for (int i=0, j=1; i<size; i++) {
    CurrencyVO currencyVO = currencyList.get(i);
    obj1[i+2] = currencyVO.getStrDerivedRefDT();
    // CurrencySetupVO cureccyCodeDes = currencyExchList.get(k);

    //if (i==0)
    obj3[0]=currencyVO.getStrCurrencyCode();
    //if (i==1)
    obj3[1]= currencyVO.getStrCurrencyDesc();
    //if (k<size) {
    obj3[i+2]=currencyVO.getStrExchRate();
    //}
    data.put(j,obj3);
    data.put(0,obj1);
    if (i==31) {//***Here for every i=31,62,93 etc J has to increment***
        j++;
    }
}
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Please take more time to format your code nicely, using tabs rather than spaces for indentation. Additionally, provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For every i=31,62,93 etc j has to increment

Then your logic should be

```
 if(i!=0 && i%31 ==0){//***Here for every i=31,62,93 etc J has to increment***
                j++;
            }
```

That % is [modulo operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html)

Comment: Except that will trigger on 0 as well. I suspect the OP *actually* wants `i % 31 == 30`, so that on the next iteration, we start off with a new value. It's hard to tell though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Added gaurd for zero. `for every i=31,62,93 etc J has to increment` gave me this thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increment J for every i=31,62......
then initialise j=0 and do check

```
if(i!=0 && i%31 == 0)
{
j++;  //j will increase for every i=31,62,.....
}
```